# Django copy-pasted code works but not typed

Tags: python, django

I am a taking the `djangobook tutorial`. I try typing the whole code myself but in some cases such as now it doesn't take mine as right and although the copy-pasted is identical it runs fine with that. How can this be fixed?

**My code(not working) is:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{$ block title %}The current time{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**The provided(Working code) by the tutorial is:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

> I get : error at line 3 Invalid block tag: 'endblock'

So sorry, i just saw my mistake and that the code wasn't identical... Thanks for the immediate editing... I guess stackoverflow is truly life saving!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 2 in your code is wrong:

```
{$ block title %}The current time{% endblock %}
```

should be

```
{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}
```

It is always a good idea to invest on an IDE (e.g. eclipse) which provides direct feedback when such errors happens and they will happen!

Comment: @Aggelos, since this answered your problem, you probably should mark it accepted by clicking the check mark <--- over there. Also, learning a diff tool is useful (e.g. vimdiff, WinMerge, KDiff, etc).

Comment: Oh ok... thanks... Sorry guys as i'm new here and to coding in general...

Answer (score 1):

```
{$ block title %}The current time{% endblock %}
```

change the dollar sign with % and you're done